# WildFly deployment only works in standalone-mode but not in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, wildfly, java-ee-7, wildfly-10

I'm trying to learn JavaEE 7 in detail and I have problems to get records from the database and display them on a JSF page.

I use WildFly 10.1.0 and Oracle XE11. I've created the following data source:

```
<datasource jndi-name="java:/supportApp" pool-name="OracleDS" enabled="true">
    <connection-url>jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:xe</connection-url>
    <driver>oracle</driver>
    <pool>
        <min-pool-size>1</min-pool-size>
        <max-pool-size>5</max-pool-size>
        <prefill>true</prefill>
    </pool>
    <security>
        <user-name>username</user-name>
        <password>password</password>
    </security>
</datasource>
```

The connection test in JBoss' admin interface is successful.

This is my `persistence.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence version="2.1"
  xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_1.xsd">
  <persistence-unit name="SupportApp" transaction-type="JTA">
  <provider>org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence</provider>
    <jta-data-source>java:/supportApp</jta-data-source>
    <shared-cache-mode>NONE</shared-cache-mode>
    <class>org.model.User</class>
  </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

When I run WildFly via the `standalone.bat` and deploy my application via `mvn  clean package wildfly:deploy` it works.

When I start the server in Eclipse and try to deploy my application with the same command it fails - since I added the JPA part. The error message I get is this:

> 14:48:40,768 INFO  [org.jboss.as.jpa] (MSC service thread 1-1) WFLYJPA0002: Read persistence.xml for SupportApp
>
> 14:48:40,782 ERROR [org.jboss.as.controller.management-operation] (management-handler-thread - 8) WFLYCTL0013: Operation ("full-replace-deployment") failed - address: ([]) - failure description: {
>
> ```
> "WFLYCTL0412: Required services that are not installed:" => ["jboss.naming.context.java.supportApp"],
>
> "WFLYCTL0180: Services with missing/unavailable dependencies" => [
>
>     "jboss.persistenceunit.\"SupportAppEJB-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar#SupportApp\" is missing [jboss.naming.context.java.supportApp]",
>
>     "jboss.persistenceunit.\"SupportAppEJB-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar#SupportApp\".__FIRST_PHASE__ is missing [jboss.naming.context.java.supportApp]"
>
> ]
> ```
>
> }

It seems to be a problem with the persistence unit, but I don't uderstand what the problem is and how I can solve it. Any suggestions?

Comment: Did you create your DataSource inside your Wildfly container?

Comment: @BuhakeSindi I created the DataSource in Wildfly AdminConsole and also in Eclipse "Data Source Explorer". Both with same name and properties

Comment: So, what datasource name did you give it on Wildfly?

Comment: @BuhakeSindi The DataSource part of the standalone.xml is posted in the question: `jndi-name="java:/supportApp" pool-name="OracleDS"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It figuered out that when eclipse asked me about the server runtime it installed a second wildfly application server. therefore my changes in the `standalone.xml` of the manually installed one didn't take account in the server eclipse started. After changing the server runtime to the path where I manually installed wildfly and configured the datasource it works like a charm.